# How to check Firebase project's country?

Tags: firebase

I want to check my Firebase project's country, but I cannot find any official documentation and any information in the "Project setting" section.

How do I check my project's country?

Also, how does it inflects my project functionality?

Comment: Do you need to check that programatically? Or in the console?

Comment: Preferred from Firebase website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to know the location of your project inside the Firebase Console, then you should go to "Project settings":

[image]

And in the "General" tab, right under "Your project" you'll see a section called "Default GCP resource location". By default, it's "us-central". If you have set another location when you have created the project, then you'll see that one.

> Also, how does it inflects my project functionality?

No. The single problem that you might have, which is not related to the functionality, is that you might encounter slower connections. That's why you should always consider setting the location closer to your audience.